# image manipulation package in R need

Tags: r, image

Please advise some R packages on rotating or flipping image on R.
Thru package  and , i'm able to read pic and turn into matrices (or data frame), however, duto the angle of shooting, the photo is tiled (or not directly facing me). I would like to manipulate the data, so I can adjust the angle.

My plan is to define the normal line of the left pic, and recalculate the angle, but failed. Guess there could be some image manipulation packages for this.

Have tried the CRAN TASKS, yet, most of the packages are for creating images, not to manipulate the outside-in images.

[image]

Comment: check out `magick` package

Comment: Thank you, sir. Will try now.

Comment: you can read the vignette first and see if it satisfies your requirements. it is very well written

Comment: @chinsoon just checked the `magick` package, it's quite nice. Yet not for my need. I am looking for a 3D-rotation function for images, and it's more like 2D-stretch. Still thanks for the promptly support.

Comment: you prob need some affine transformation. this package might help: `RNiftyReg`

Comment: seems interesting. I am working on it. Many thanks. @chinsoon12